# CSS media queries stopped working after setting css with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm trying to make a sidebar menu to achieve a responsive design.

I have a container div `#wrapper` for the page and a sidebar div for the menu `#sidebar-wrapper`.

On desktop view when `screen width > 768px` both wrappers are shown, and when `browser's width <= 768px` the sidebar disappears.

It worked with me with CSS media queries, but after I added a jquery function to toggle showing/hiding the sidebar by a button, the CSS media queries stopped working after the first click.

Why did that happen, and how to get both of them to work?

**JQUERY**

```
var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
var sidebar = $("#sidebar-wrapper");

$("#btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    collapse();
});

function collapse(){
    if(sidebar.css("left") == "0px")
    {
        sidebar.css("left","220px");
        wrapper.css("margin-left","220px");
    }
    else
    {
        sidebar.css("left","0px");
        wrapper.css("margin-left","0px");
    }
}
```

**CSS** *(I'm using LESS here)*

```
#wrapper{ 
   .
   .
   margin-left: 220px;  /* for left sidebar */
   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px){
      margin-left: 0;
   }
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    .
    .
    left: 220px;
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px){  
        left: 0;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `css()` method, it sets the DOM element's `style` property, which is more specific (has higher priority) than the stylesheet. You might want to create classes with predefined style and toggle those classes on the given elements. For example:

```
function collapse() {
    sidebar.toggleClass('collapsed');
    wrapper.toggleClass('collapsed');
}
```

The above will work provided that you have the following in your CSS:

```
#wrapper.collapsed {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.collapsed {
    left: 0;
}
```